# Expresso Store: Destination based sales tax

Tags: add-on, expresso-store

My client lives in Washington State and they have destination-based sales tax, meaning anytime they ship something to a customer within the state, taxes must be calculated based on the customers address (not just zipcode - that would be too easy).  It's my understanding that roughly 20 states are now doing this with new ones adopting the process monthly.

This isn't something to snub our noses at -- it's the law in many of our states and our clients can get into serious trouble if they don't comply.  Disappointingly I've emailed Exp:resso about this issue three times now asking for help and even offering to pay them to develop this, but have received zero response.

Does anyone have a solution for this growing problem?

Comment: Sorry you have not received a response to your email enquiry. Did you get an immediate response from our support ticket system? I will look into this for you.

Comment: Yes, I got an auto-response each time I emailed.

Comment: Following this up via email. Will post an answer on SE once we reach a solution.

Comment: @AdrianMacneil Can you post an answer for this?

Comment: Did you ever find or build a solution for this? I am need of this exact same thing. If you have found a solution could you send the info for it? If you built a solution would you be willing to sell it?

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here. The first is that in Store 1, taxes were calculated based on the billing address rather than the shipping address. This has been fixed in Store 2, and taxes are now calculated based on the shipping address.

Secondly, there is the problem that some states in the US have extremely complicated tax laws, where the correct tax rate must be determined based on the specific address (and even ZIP codes are not always granular enough to determine the correct tax rate). The only real solution to this is to use one of the API services available which will return up to date tax rates for each address. Store doesn't currently integrate with any of these services, but it would certainly be possible to build using the extension hooks.